# removing a path or image or watermark from all pages of a pdf with adobe acrobat

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, foxit-reader

i have a pdf and in all pages of this pdf there is a gray color path and i can not remove them.
is there a way to quickly remove all of these paths from all pages with adobe acrobat or foxit phandomPDF. here is one page of pdf and i want to remove gray picture at background.

[image: screenshot]

i tried using remove background, remove header and footer, remove watermark,... and some other remove commands in adobe acrobat but i didn't get any result.
any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Why don't you contact the author of the PDF and ask for a version without watermark?

Comment: If this document was originally a word document, then you would have to convert it back to a word document, in order to remove the watermark.  The simplest solution is to have the author of the document remove the watermark.